# Saving credentials for subdomain in iOS keychain

Tags: ios, keychain, password-autofill

I have an iOS in SwiftUI and I have `domain.com` as well as `subdomain.domain.com` setup with the `apple-app-site-association` file. This is working so far and my app opens when these links are called.

In my app I sign up with the standard keychain heuristics and the TextField `textContentType(.username)` and `textContentType(.newPassword)` of iOS that detects username and password and saves them into the keychain. This is all working so far, however I make my API call to `subdomain.domain.com` but iOS saves the keychain item under `domain.com`.

My `apple-app-site-association` file for `domain.com` looks like this:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "XXXXXXX.com.domain.app",
        "paths": [
          "/app/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My `apple-app-site-association` file for `subdomain.domain.com` looks like this:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "XXXXXXX.com.domain.app",
        "paths": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [
      "XXXXXXX.com.domain.app"
    ]
  }
}
```

My Associate Domain entitlement in the app looks like this:

```
applinks:domain.com
applinks:subdomain.domain.com
webcredentials:subdomain.domain.com
```

How can I tell iOS to save the item under `subdomain.domain.com`?